# Nascar Python Project

Tags: python, time, printing, while-loop, distance

I'm trying to make a python program where 20 cars go random speeds which update every minute (set as a second right now).  It tracks the distance they drive, and the first to 500 miles wins.

But, I get this error when I run it:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\NASCAR.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Car:
  File "E:\Python\NASCAR.py", line 10, in Car
    while miles < 500.00:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < float()`

I'm not sure how to fix this error, so any help is appreciated.

```
import time
from random import randint
class Car:
    miles = 0.00
    carnumber = 0
    #makes list of the cars, their speeds, and their distances. carspeed[1] is the same vehicle as cardistance[1] and "Jamie McMurray" under the Chip Ganassi Racing with Felix Stone team.
    carspeed = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    cardistance = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    Cars = {"Alex Bowman":"BK Racing", "Jamie McMurray":"Chip Ganassi Racing with Felix Sabates", "David Ragan":"Front Row Motorsports", "Martin Truex Jr":"Furniture Row Racing", "Casey Mears":"Germain Racing", "JJ Yeley":"Go FAS Racing", "Jeff Gordon":"Hendrick Motorsports", "Timmy Hill":"Hillman-Circle Sport LLC", "Justin Allgaier":"H Scott Motorsports", "Jor Nemechek":"Identity Ventures Racing", "Kyle Busch":"Joe Gibbs Racing", "A.J Allmendinger":"Bushs Baked Beans", "Alex Bowman":"R Pepper", "Aric Almirola":"Smithfield foods", "Austin Dillon":"Dow Chemicals", "Black Koch":"MDS", "Bobby Labonte":"Pheonix Racing", "Brad Keselowski":"Miller Lite", "Brett moffitt":"Land Castle Title", "Brian Keselowski":"BK Motors"}
    while miles < 500.00:
        time.sleep(1)
        while carnumber != 19:
            carspeed[carnumber] = randint(0,120)
            print(carspeed)
            cardistance[carnumber] += carspeed[carnumber]/60
            carnumber += 1
        mile = cardistance.sort
        miles = mile()
        print (miles)
```

Comment: Please give the **full text** of the traceback, as it will point you to exactly where the problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop crashes on its second evaluation of `miles < 500.00`, because `miles` is a float the first time through (which is OK), but `None` the second (which is absolutely *not* OK).  This is what the error message was telling you.

More specifically, `sort` doesn't return anything, so `miles = mile()` assigns to `miles` the `None` returned by `cardistance.sort()`.

As an aside, your `Car` class isn't really a class...  At least, it does nothing anyone expects a class to do, and you never use it.  Your entire program runs only as a side-effect of class definition --- in other words, by accident.

You probably wanted a *function* (or several), not a class definition.  Then, later, you would call that function, ideally from `main`.  Something like:

```
def race():
    # As above...

# Later...
def main():
    race()
    return

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

I suggest you re-read the [Python Tutorial's "Defining Functions" section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).  Then move on to the [Python Tutorial's "Classes" chapter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), and contrast what you're doing with how classes are typically created and used.